# Failed to run Apache Singa after installation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Followed the [instruction](https://github.com/apache/incubator-singa/blob/master/doc/en/docs/installation.md) and installed [Apache Singa v1.0.0](https://singa.incubator.apache.org/en/index.html) from the [wheel](http://comp.nus.edu.sg/~dbsystem/singa/assets/file/pb2.6/singa-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl) successfully, but failed to run it below,

```
(singa) $ pip list | grep singa
singa (1.0.0)

(singa) $ python
> import singa
> ImportError: No module named '_singa_wrap'

(singa) $ find -name "*singa_wrap*"
singa_wrap.py
singa_wrap.pyc
_singa_wrap.so
```

Seemed something suspicious with [Swig module extension](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn9). Any suggestions?

**@EDIT**

Verified that `protobuf 2.6.1` already installed globally below,

```
(singa) $ python -c "from singa import _singa_wrap"
undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameEv

$ ldd _singa_wrap.so
libprotobuf.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9

$ dpkg -S libprotobuf.so.9
libprotobuf9v5

$ apt-cache policy libprotobuf9v5
Installed: 2.6.1-1.3
```

**@Solution**

`Singa` starts dancing now after [protobuf 2.6.1](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz) being successfully installed locally on `Ubuntu 16.04` below,

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip # gcc-5 required thus installed
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5   60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc # to choose gcc-4.8
```

The rest then follows the answer `@Wei` below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the approaches in the first FAQ http://singa.apache.org/en/docs/installation.html#faq

In addition, you can check the dependent libs of _singa_wrap.so (go to /Python2.7/site-packages/singa/, and `ldd _singa_wrap.so`. If any library (e.g. cudnn or protobuf) is not found, then try to install it or export the library path.

There is a ticket for your issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SINGA-255.

Will update you once it is done.

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems your error is related to protobuf (could be caused by multiple versions of protobuf on your computer). Here is the solution,

1. Download protobuf (protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz on github) and decompress the tar file
2. Install protobuf into /home//local/ by

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/home/<yourname>/local
   make && make install
   echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<yourname>/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. `pip uninstall singa`
4. `pip install <path to the wheel file>`

Comment: Thanks, could you have a look at the update on the OP?

Comment: Same error as before even if [protobuf 2.6.1](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz) rebuilt & linked locally.

Comment: Error is still: undefined symbol: '_ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameEv'? Can you post the result of ldd _singa_wrap.so? What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: We have updated the whl file which compiled protobuf into it. Hence, you don't need to install protobuf and openblas by yourself. Please try the new whl file. http://singa.apache.org/en/docs/installation.html#from-wheel

Comment: [Training MINST](https://github.com/apache/incubator-singa/tree/master/examples/mnist) got core dumped at `epoch 0` with the [new wheel](http://comp.nus.edu.sg/~dbsystem/singa/assets/file/ubuntu1404/singa-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl) on `Ubuntu 16.04`, while the previous installation with manual local `protobuf` build works well.

Comment: It is caused by the OS. The wheel file was built on 14.04. If you want to run SINGA on 16.04, please follow [these steps](http://singa.apache.org/en/docs/installation.html#from-source) to build it from source. We will create the wheels files for 16.04 later.